# hexdump converts CRLF to LF under Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, line-endings

When dumping the contents of a text file with Windows line endings (CRLF) using `hexdump` under Cygwin/bash, `hexdump` seems to open the file as a text file and convert the line endings from Windows (CRLF) to UNIX (LF) which makes the dump incorrect.

I am running bash 4.3.42 under Cygwin x86_64 running on Windows 7:

```
mgd@mgd-win7vm /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(4)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
...snip...
```

The `C:` is mounted on `/cygdrive/c` as “text”:

```
mgd@mgd-win7vm /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ mount
C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (text,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

Now, we create a text file with one line:

```
mgd@mgd-win7vm /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ echo "Hello" > textfile
```

The file is 7 bytes long as expected ("Hello" + CR + LF):

```
mgd@mgd-win7vm /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ stat textfile
  File: 'textfile'
  Size: 7               Blocks: 1          IO Block: 65536  regular file
...snip...
```

When we dump it using `od` we get the correct output:

```
mgd@mgd-win7vm /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ od -ctx1 textfile
0000000   H   e   l   l   o  \r  \n
         48  65  6c  6c  6f  0d  0a
0000007
```

However, when using `hexdump` CR+LF is converted to LF:

```
mgd@mgd-win7vm /cygdrive/c/tmp
$ hexdump -C textfile
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a                                 |Hello.|
00000006
```

Is this a bug?

Is there a way to force `hexdump` to open files in binary mode?